# tf.string_split() Errors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using python 3.7, tensorflow version 1.14.0.

I am trying to use `tf.string_split()` to get class names from a dataset's directory.

When I use this format,

```
path1 = 'c:/users/path/to/directory/'
def get_label(path):
    # convert the path to a list of path components
    # present path as vector
    parts = tf.string_split([path], '/')
    # The 2nd to last is the class-directory
    return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES

get_label(path1)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'SparseTensor' object is not subscriptable
```

And if I use this format:

```
def get_label(path):
    # convert the path to a list of path components
    parts = tf.string_split(path, '/')
    # The 2nd to last is the class-directory
    return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES
get_label(path1)
```

I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: input must be a vector, got shape: [] [Op:StringSplit]
```

I gave it a vector and the result isn't sub-scriptable, I gave it a shape and it can't split that. I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `tf.string_split`, it will return `SparseTensor` type, which has `indices` and `values` attributes. I guess you want to do this,

```py
path1 = 'c:/users/path/to/directory/'
def get_label(path):
    # convert the path to a list of path components
    # present path as vector
    parts = tf.string_split([path], '/')
    # The 2nd to last is the class-directory
    return tf.equal(parts.values[-2], CLASS_NAMES)

eq_t = get_label(path1)
```